# is there a command to check if there was any antivirus installed?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, antivirus

I'm looking for a command to list what *antivirus(s)* are installed on Windows. If there is currently none installed, I would like it to *indicate this*.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the `wmic` command with a `findstr` command. Should work on <kbd>Windows Vista</kbd> and later

`wmic /node:localhost /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct Get DisplayName | findstr /V /B /C:displayName || echo No Antivirus installed`

[Reference](https://superuser.com/questions/514232/get-antivirus-windows-commandline)

Comment: how about update? for example if antivirus installed but need updating to work properly

Comment: anything that make antivirus not workable, such as updating? or needing Activation (License)

Comment: Most of the major antivirus companies have monitor tools to tell you if a computer in your network does have up to date antivirus.

Answer (score 2):

At least in windows 10 (at this moment I can not test it in another version, but it should at least work for windows 7 or later)

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct get * /value
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to list all running antivirus in your system:

```
WMIC /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName /Format:List
```